# "Hair" vs "hairs"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

When we add *s* at the end of a word, it refers to more units of the thing. For example, *a car* vs *cars*.

Why is it that when we refer to *hair*, it is kind of the other way around?

> 1) Your **hair** looks great (comment on all your hair)
>
> 2) You dyed some of your **hairs** (comment on some of your hair)

Comment: Note that it would actually be more typical to phrase 2) as "you dyed some of your *hair*" (no "s"), because the hair you dyed is still an undifferentiated mass (though, as a mass, it is differentiated from the remaining mass of undyed hair).  You'd only really use "hairs" (with the s) when you literally want to count them ("I found 5 hairs on my pillow this morning! Maybe I'm going bald."), or want to focus on the individual strands themselves to emphasize their discreteness, or at least small number ("I plucked some hairs that were growing between my eyebrows").

Comment: So it depends on if it is used in a countable or uncountable situation as Jasper stated

Comment: Yes, but given the nature of your question, I thought you might be unfamiliar with the terms "count noun" and "mass noun", so I was trying to illustrate the idea more concretely.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I am not familiar with these 2 terms hence I didn't pay attention.  Also it looks like it's a duplicated question.

Answer (score 2):

*Hair* can be used as an uncountable noun:

> You have too much **hair**

or a countable noun in which case its plural is *hairs*:

> There are three **hairs** here.