# Use of "hair" when talking about plural people

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

Which is correct:
a) Men's hair goes through a lot.
b) Men's hair go through a lot.
c) Neither.  Better to say "A man's hair goes through a lot" to talk about men's hair in general

Answer (score 0):

According to these:

- [Is 'hair' singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9951/is-hair-singular-or-plural)
- ["Hair" vs "hairs"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189253/hair-vs-hairs)

You can't say "Men's hair go through a lot."

To speak about hair in general you can say, "A man's hair goes through a lot" or "Man's (or Men's) hair goes through a lot". You can also use the word "male".

Comment: Please close-vote obvious duplicates rather than listing them in an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth With pleasure if only I knew how.

Comment: Access the menu 'close' from [share edit close flag] (I'm assuming they're not restricted) and fill in required data.